# Export LinkedIn Contacts

Tags: android, linkedin-api

How can I export all LinkedIn Contacts on a Android Application?

I just finsih with the Auth but I don't Know how to export all the contacts to my Android app.

Comment: This Link Might Help You
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/185906-import-linkedin-contacts-to-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

Install

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkedin.android&hl=en

And you get all your contacts from LinkedIn synced with your Android Contacts.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't wanna install nothing, I just want a example code to apply at my application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. A couple of years ago, LinkedIn cut off the ability to access a user's contacts via their API (unless you're part of their approved partner program). See https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply